# "working" in meaning "functioning"

Tags: meaning, grammar

Can I say "the mechanism use tool X in its **working**" or it will be incorrect? Also, can I use *its* in the sentence or it is better to remove it from the sentence?

Comment: "in its working" is not incorrect, but I would prefer "when operating".

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are trying to convey.

Comment: @TrevorD I'm trying use the word `working` as noun. It seems like it is not incorrect http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/working_2 ,  but i didn't find if anyone use it such way

Comment: Telling me you're trying to use it as a noun does not actually help me to understand what your sentence is trying to convey.

Comment: Supplementing my last comment: we do not know what type of "mechanism" you are referring to: a machine, a car, a hand-tool, ...?

Comment: @TrevorD it is a technical system with different parts interacting with each other

Comment: "One of the parts/tools used in the mechanism is X ..."

Answer (score 3):

I assume you meant to say ***The mechanism uses tool X, when it is working.***?

Normally, if the mechanism is in working order but switched off, and you mean that it uses "tool X" when it is switched on and going, then the better term to use would be *operating* - as @Graffito has pointed out in a comment. You could also say, slightly less formally *...uses tool X when going*.

Saying *...uses tool X when working*, carries a slight suggestion that the mechanism is currently broken down and not in working order.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I tried to add this as a comment as I am not confident it is the right answer given the sparse nature of the context, but it was just too long.

"Working(s)" as a noun generally refers to something quite specific depending on context. For example, a mathematics exam paper might ask you to solve a problem and *show your working*, meaning write down every step you took to reach your answer. "Workings" as a noun generally means either the result of a process ("mine workings" being what's left after mining, such as the tunnels and spoil) or the actual mechanisms that make up a machine. EDIT: (I pressed enter by mistake) - in the example sentence in your question, I would be inclined to use "work" if you mean its operation, or "works" if you mean the product of its operation.

If I misunderstood the question please let me know and I will try to refine the answer (if I can) accordingly.